# How to set two decimal digit in html cell?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-c++, siemens-nx

The output of the data is something like x.xxxxxxxx in html.

I want to set in two decimal like
x.xx.

My code is

```
"<TD ALIGN=CENTER>$value</TD>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you should make the change in JavaScript but you can also use JS in HTML using the script tag. So, you can use:

```
<TD ALIGN=CENTER><script>document.write(parseFloat($value).toFixed(2));</script></TD>
```